# get values from several dropdownlists

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, drop-down-menu, checkboxlist

In my Page_Init method, I create 1 checkboxlist (filled with items) and several dropdownlists equal to the amount of items in checkboxlist (6checkboxlistitems -> 6 dropdownlists).

Both, items en dropdownlists are bounded to data (items represent each day of the week, dropdownlists are filled with 4 timeframes of a day). I create a dropdownlist for every item and give it id = item.text.

Code from the Page_Init method:

```
        foreach (ListItem item in chkListContact.Items)
        {
            ddlTimePeriod = new DropDownList();
            ddlTimePeriod.ID = item.Text;
            ddlTimePeriod.CssClass = "dropdownlistContact";
            ddlTimePeriod.DataSource = datasrcTimePeriod;
            ddlTimePeriod.DataTextField = "TimePeriodName";
            ddlTimePeriod.DataValueField = "TimeToCallID";
            ddlTimePeriod.DataBind();
            dllPanel.Controls.Add(ddlTimePeriod);
            dllPanel.ID = "dllPanel";
        }
```

Code from the BUTTON_CLICK:

```
        foreach (ListItem item in chkListContact.Items)
        {
            //
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                //Here I want to get the values from the selected items and corresponding dropdownlist value and send it to database
                cmdTimeToCall.Parameters.Clear();
                cmdTimeToCall.Parameters.Add("PersonId", personid);
                cmdTimeToCall.Parameters.Add("DayOfWeekId", Convert.ToInt32(item.Value));
                cmdTimeToCall.Parameters.Add("TimeToCallId", --VALUE FROM DROPDOWNLIST OF CORRESPONDING ITEM --);

            }
        }
```

How can you take the value from each dropdownlist when the corresponding item is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (item.Selected)
{
    DropDownList ddlTimePeriod = (DropDownList) dllPanel.FindControl(item.Text);

    // now use ddlTimePeriod.SelectedItem.Text, ddlTimePeriod.SelectedItem.Value

    cmdTimeToCall.Parameters.Clear();
    cmdTimeToCall.Parameters.Add("PersonId", personid);
    cmdTimeToCall.Parameters.Add("DayOfWeekId", Convert.ToInt32(item.Value));
    cmdTimeToCall.Parameters.Add("TimeToCallId", --VALUE FROM DROPDOWNLIST OF CORRESPONDING ITEM --);

}
```